# How do I pass a parameter value to a Conversion class in java?

Tags: jsf

I am trying to pass a value to a conversion class in JSF/SEAM

```
public class ValueConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
    // logic etc here.
```

My xhtml is:

```
<f:converter converterId="ValueConverter">
<f:attribute name="theMaxOrderSize" id="maxorder" value="#{_cartItem.item.maxOrderSize}"/>
</f:converter>
```

How do I pass a parameter value to a Conversion class in java? Am I starting off wrong? I am using JSF 1.2 I think..

Answer (score 6):

Bhesh is entirely right. You should be doing the validating job inside a [`Validator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html).

As to the concrete problem, move the `<f:attribute>` out of the `<f:converter>` (or `<f:validator>` if you're listening to us) into the input component and then use [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) to obtain it. E.g.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:validator validatorId="valueValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="theMaxOrderSize" id="maxorder" value="#{_cartItem.item.maxOrderSize}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

with

```
Object theMaxOrderSize = component.getAttributes().get("theMaxOrderSize");
// ...
```

*(where `component` is the `UIComponent` argument of the `validate()` method, it represents the parent input component)*

You can cast it to `Integer` or whatever object type the `#{_cartItem.item.maxOrderSize}` represents.

Answer (score 3):

That's something you should be doing with Validator. Converter is just to convert from String to Object and Object to String. You are trying to validate in a Converter.

> How do I pass a parameter value to a Conversion class in java?

That's not correct, you don't need to pass a parameter to a Converter. it should be -

> How do I access a parameter in a Converter in JSF?

You can use FacesContext -

```
context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

I think you got a whole lot of readings to do. Best of luck!

If you want to add attributes to your converter, then use StateHolder -

```
public class ValueConverter implements Converter, StateHolder {
```